# Multiple RTMP inputs - picture in picture - stream offline handling

Tags: gstreamer, rtmp

I'm using gstreamer to make a picture-in-picture composition of two rtmp inputs into an rtmp output.
I've managed to create a pipeline that works very well when both streams are offline
However, when one of the rtmp streams is not live when starting the pipeline - the pipeline does not start.

Does anyone know how to overcome this issue, and make sure the pipeline is not blocked if one rtmp source is offline?

Comment: How did you manage to get two RTMP inputs and do the PiP and mux it down to one stream? Only wondering because I am trying to do something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71728474/3331416

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to insert ***identity*** into compositor input sub-pipelines.

Simulating 2 sources on localhost with:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! x264enc insert-vui=1 ! h264parse config-interval=1 ! mpegtsmux ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink port=5004
```

(and second source the same to port 5005), the following runs fine for 0, 1 or 2 sources active at launch time:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v \
   udpsrc port=5004 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=MP2T,clock-rate=90000,payload=33 ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=300 ! rtpmp2tdepay ! tsdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! identity ! queue ! comp.sink_0 \
   udpsrc port=5005 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=MP2T,clock-rate=90000,payload=33 ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=300 ! rtpmp2tdepay ! tsdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! identity ! queue ! comp.sink_1 \
   compositor name=comp sink_0::xpos=0 sink_0::ypos=0 sink_0::width=320 sink_0::height=240 sink_1::xpos=0 sink_1::ypos=240 sink_1::width=320 sink_1::height=240 ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=480 ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink
```

For rtmp, with mpeg audio from first source, it would be something like:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v \
   rtmpsrc <your source1 and options> ! flvdemux name=demux0 ! queue ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! identity ! queue ! comp.sink_0 \
   rtmpsrc <your source2 and options> ! flvdemux name=demux1 ! queue ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! identity ! queue ! comp.sink_1 \
   compositor name=comp sink_0::xpos=0 sink_0::ypos=0 sink_0::width=320 sink_0::height=240 sink_1::xpos=0 sink_1::ypos=240 sink_1::width=320 sink_1::height=240 ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=480 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink \
   demux0. ! queue ! audio/mpeg ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink
```

Comment: Hi I tried your pipelines but used "autovideosink" instead of "xvimagesink", and the pipeline is 'PLAYING' but I cannot see any output

Comment: Be aware that it may take up to 10 seconds to connect, setup and decode/display. Autovideosink can select various display sinks depending on your host. In case of NVIDIA graphics, the sink may expect buffers in NVMM memory, so you would try adding nvvidconv: `... ! videoconvert ! nvvidconv ! autovideosink`.

Comment: Thanks @SeB I found the problem in my case, running on a mac I had to specify "address=localhost" for udpsrc and "host=localhost" for udpsink and it started working! Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: quick question, do you know how I can add audio from one of the sources into the final mix?

Comment: Edited my aswer with some info, but not really tried because I don't have an RTMP server.

Comment: I managed to get the mix running via 3 different pipelines.
Sometimes one of the streams in the compositor freezes, but the RTMP stream itself works fine. I suspect it could be some issue with dropping frames because they are too much in the past.
I see this error continuously a lot when debugging

0:00:43.145154187     9 0xffff44021ea0 WARN                  flvmux gstflvmux.c:1247:gst_flv_mux_buffer_to_tag_internal:<mux:sink_1> Got backwards dts! (0:00:31.200000000 < 0:00:31.488000000)

Comment: Hi. Can you please explain how is inserting identity elements can resolve this problem? My understanding is that identity is primarily used a diagnostic tool. I'm having a similar problem and adding them to by sub-pipelines did not resolve it.